# Will the IRS go after foreign countries' pension if you owe taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, non-resident, pension

I am a 70 year old retired Irish citizen living in Ireland. I did live in the USA. Unfortunately, I recently learned that I owe the IRS $15k in taxes from a 401k withdrawal. I own nothing in the USA but I am receiving Social Security and a private pension. Can the IRS attach my pension?

Comment: it is doubtful that the IRS would go after your pension (assuming they could, which I don't know), but you will probably not be able to travel to the US in the future without risking them taking you in until you pay. They will go after your US social security payments, though. work with them, they wouldn't let you go hungry.